# How to add <i class="something"></i> in Thymeleaf problem with quotes

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

Spring on Tomcat :

I want to add icon name for example :

```
  <div class="weatherIcon"><i class="wi-night-sleet"></i></div>
```

from http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/. HTML +CSS

When I enter it myself like in the example above. Everything works correctly.

I'm trying to replace the text by replacing String from controller.
Controller :

```
model.addAttribute("Icon",g.gson().getCurrently().ChangedIcon());

<div class="weather-Icon"><i class= < th:text="${Icon}"/></i></div>
```

String :

```
 ......//some code///
    case "clear-night":
    return '"' + "wi-night-sleet" + '"';
    .....///etc
```

But i get result like this :

```
<div class="weatherIcon"><i class= <>&quot;wi-night-sleet&quot;</i></i></div>
```

And I do not get icon only string on web

Comment: Can you try this: <div class="weather-Icon"><i th:class="${Icon}"></i></div> AND also remove the extra quotes from the return statement? Let me know if it works

Comment: @Mihai Yes it's works ! Thank You very much ! I'm really appreciate that !

Comment: ok, I'll add it as an answer and you can approve it. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the HTML code to:

```html
<div class="weather-Icon"><i th:class="${Icon}"></i></div>
```

and also remove the extra quotes from the return statement